# Unable solve parametric equations (and transform them back into regular form)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

At the top of page 6 of this document - https://www.ma.utexas.edu/users/davis/375/LECTURES/L11/cauchy.pdf - three parameterized equations are specified -

1. $\frac{dt}{ds} = x$
2. $\frac{dx}{ds} = -2xt$
3. $\frac{du}{ds} = 2ut$

It says that they lead to the following solutions -

$x + t^2 = C_0$

$xu = C_1$

I am not able arrive at these solutions.

I get $\frac{t}{x} = s + c_0$ from $1.$ above. And I don't know what to do with $2.$ or $3.$ as it seems $u, x$ and $t$ are all functions of $s$ (as they are parameterized with $s$), so I don't know how to solve them as I can't used separation of variables or integrating factors. How do I solve these equations to give the solutions listed above? Is there something straightforward that I am overlooking?..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like substitution does the trick. The first equation directly gives $x$, so plug that into equation 2 to get 
$$ \frac{dx}{ds}= -2t\frac{dt}{ds}.$$
Integrate both sides and you get the first relation. You can do the same thing to get rid of the $t$ in equations 2 and 3 and get
$$ \frac{1}{u}\frac{du}{ds}=-\frac{1}{x}\frac{dx}{ds}.$$

I don't believe you can integrate the equations individually as you tried to. For example, for your solution to the first equation it looks like you just rewrote it as 
$$ \frac{1}{x}\frac{dt}{ds}=1$$
and integrated from there. But the left side can't be integrated directly unless we know for sure that $x$ does not depend on $s$.

Comment: Ok thanks. I rewrote the first equation as $\frac{dt}{x} = ds$. In that case it seems we can integrate?

Comment: Correct. Or at least, you can't integrate the equation in a simple way. Taking a derivative of the expression you wrote confirms this. Since $x$ could depend on $s$, we need the chain rule and get $\frac{1}{x}\frac{dt}{ds}-\frac{t}{x^2}\frac{dx}{ds}=1$. Unless $\frac{dx}{ds}=0$, we don't recover equation 1.

Comment: What was the chain rule you applied there, I'm not sure how you got the $-\frac{t}{x^2}$?

Comment: It would be great if you could show me what you did there mate, I think this might be the cause of alot of problems I've had with paramaterizations in various equations today! Did you apply the chain rule to $\frac{dt}{x} = ds$?

Comment: @sonicboom I took derivative of the equation you got stuck at, $\frac{t}{x}=s+C_0$, to check and see if you recovered the first equation. Since both $t$ and $x$ could depend on $s$, you have to use the chain rule, and you find you don't recover the original parametric. I don't know how you could make progress looking at just 1 equation alone in this case.